# Make electron app icon bounce on start up

Tags: macos, electron, dock

It seems that the `app.dock.bounce()` command only works if the app does not have focus.

Is there any way to make the dock icon bounce when the app starts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Electron, but the API of macOS allows to request the users attention only when the application is in the background. When the app gets activated, the attention request is automatically canceled. The intended use of this system is to inform the user that an *background* app wants its attention. It makes no sense to do this when already in the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mschmidt pointed out, and confirmed elsewhere, the dock icon cannot be bounced when the app has focus.